# I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql using php for my Flex Mobile application, but no luck

Tags: php, android, apache-flex, mobile, authentication

I am creating a login based application and this is what I have so far. I am trying to read each field into a separate textarea. I have tried to bind the data etc. I do get a output in the textarea, but it prints all the fields in one textarea. Please help.

```
<?php

selectDB();

function selectDB() {

    $usertoken = $_POST['usertoken'];



    //Database service vars
    $databasehost = "localhost";
    $databasename = "morerandom";
    $databasetable = "random";
    $databaseusername = "root"; 
    $databasepassword = "root"; 

    $con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());


    $query = "SELECT username, useremail, firstname, lastname FROM $databasetable WHERE usertoken='$usertoken'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count)
    {
        $rows = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        echo $rows[0]->username . "\n";
           echo "\n";
        echo $rows[0]->useremail . "\n";    
          echo $rows[0]->firstname . "\n";  

         $first = $rows[0]->lastname;
         echo $first;
         // echo "$lastname;"

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Token not valid';
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: you can try encoding the data as an json object

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is `just one string`. There are better way to retrieve this kind of data from the server side([XML](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/29/dynamically-loading-xml-files-using-the-httpservice-tag/) or [AMF](http://silexlabs.org/amfphp/)).

If you want to go ahead with your method then split the string using '\n' as a delimiter but check first that the server response is not `'Token not valid'`.

So something like this should work:

First remove the `echo "\n";` line under the `echo $rows[0]->username . "\n";`

```
var responseArray:Array = theStringResult.split('\n');
```

So now the `responseArray` stores the **username** at position 0, **useremail** at position 1, **firstname** at position 2 and **lastname** at position 3.

But again, you are sending data from the server as raw text and this is not the best way to do it. Check [this link](http://corlan.org/2008/10/10/flex-and-php-remoting-with-amfphp/) to see how this can be done using [AMFPHP](http://silexlabs.org/amfphp/).